# Set up "smart" DNS server

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I'm in a **restricted network** and I want to setup a smart DNS server for personal use.
I don't want to use any VPN services since it required setup on my Windows 8. I don't want to encrypt internet connection but only to geolocate to watch Netflix and Hulu.

Is there any application that can perform this smart DNS?

Can you give me a headstart so I can check and probably set it up myself?

Comment: DNS isn't the only thing used in geolocation. In fact, many services that are restricted to a given reason often inspect your IP address to determine your eligibility. A VPN service with an endpoint in your desired country is the only reasonably reliable way to get around the restrictions you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I found guide to set this up using a US based VPS running DNSmasq and haproxy and requiring a OpenWRT based router (though should be possible with DD-WRT also) running at your home.

Wayback Machine Link:

[DIY DNS unblocking (using a US VPS, haproxy and OpenWRT) | Allan Willems Joergensen - OnDemand](https://web.archive.org/web/20141129082118/https://nowhere.dk/articles/diy-dns-unblocking-using-a-us-vps-haproxy-and-openwrt)